# UnsatisfiedLinkError in cocos2dx cpp test in eclipse

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i am newbie to cocos2dx and just have made setup for cocos2dx in ubuntu with eclipse and android SDK  and NDK,I have gone through all the steps describes in various tutorials and successfully imported the CPP test sample from cocos2dx in eclipse,now when i run the application it crashed and mly logcat is as below:

**logcat**

```
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): Process: org.cocos2dx.cpp_tests, PID: 1744
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cpp_tests from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cocos2dx.cpp_tests-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.cpp_tests-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:207)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:222)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
```

05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-28 08:53:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)